# Where is the MVEL Language Reference found?

Tags: reference, mvel

http://www.codehaus.org/ is no longer a supported site.  No pointer to a new site for MVEL is mentioned.  The github site: https://github.com/mvel/mvel has source and a few trivial samples but no reference.

Comment: Likely nowhere except archives for the immediate future, until the devs put in a redirect or host it on GH.

Comment: This date seems reasonably well crawled:
    https://web.archive.org/web/20141020101757/http://mvel.codehaus.org/

Later ones yield a lot of 302s

Comment: This is what really annoys me about SO these days.  

>  Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." – Tunaki, Kyll, Paul Roub, Jarrod Roberson, Samuel Liew  

That is exactly what I attempted to do via the title and listing the common places I had already looked.  2500 views later (mostly after being closed) and some great answers have been provided with newer locations.

Comment: For better or worse, SO isn't for finding off-site resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been deleted from Wikipedia as well, and moved to Wikisource: [MVEL Language Guide](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/MVEL_Language_Guide)

Comment: And now it's deleted from Wikisource too

Comment: alternate location: http://mvel.documentnode.com/#language-guide-for-2.0

Answer (score 7):

I have arranged the documentation into markdown format and hosted a HTML version here: http://mvel.documentnode.com/

Please feel free to fork from here: https://github.com/jiakuan/mvel-doc in case anything in the doc needs to be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete Mvel reference in this archive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20141017203926/http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Operators

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed to research differences in behaviour between 1.3 and 2. Since the code for 1.3 is no longer available online.

Answer (score -1):

I was struggled with this whole website content is gone issue. I found this from the wiki, not much info but hope it's helpful for you before we have another site can redirect to.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVEL_Language_Guide

Answer (score -1):

Check out this issue on the MVEL github repo: https://github.com/mvel/mvel/issues/101

The current documentation is here: http://mvel.documentnode.com/